# Shouldn't an optional be inclusive to a non-optional type in Swift?

Tags: ios, dictionary, swift, option-type

**Updated:** with full code

I have this code:

```
struct Set<T : Hashable>: Sequence {
    var items: Dictionary<Int, T> = [:]

    func append(o: T?) {
        if let newValue = o {
            items[newValue.hashValue] = newValue
        }
    }

    func generate() -> TypeGenerator<T> {
        return TypeGenerator ( Slice<T>( items.values ) )
    }
}
```

and I get the error:

**Could not find an overload for 'subscript' that accepts the supplied arguments.**

for the line:

```
items[newValue.hashValue] = newValue
```

As far as I understand it's because `newValue`'s type is `T` rather than `T?`, meaning that it's not optional. This is because the `Dictionary`'s `subscript` for accessing the key/value pair is defined as

```
subscript (key: KeyType) -> ValueType?
```

meaning that it can only take an optional as the value. And in my case `newValue` is not an optional after validating it's not `nil`.

But isn't an optional inclusive of non-optionals? Isn't a type's optional is the type + `nil`?

Why would something that can take everything + `nil` reject a type that can't be `nil`?

**Small clarification:** the reason I check that `o` is not `nil` is to be able to call its `hashValue` which is not accessible directly from the optional or the unwrapped optional (`o!.hashValue` throws a compile error).

I  also can't replace the assignment line with

```
items[newValue.hashValue] = o
```

because it has validated that `o` is not an optional worthy of assignment even though it does not allow access to it's `hashValue` property.

Comment: hi i dont get your problem the following works for me
`class X<T : Hashable> {
var items: Dictionary<Int, T> = [:]

func append(o: T?) {
    if let newValue = o {
        items[newValue.hashValue] = newValue
    }
}
}

var x = X<String>()
var s = "a"
var so : String? = "b"
var son : String? = nil

x.append(s)
x.append(so)
x.append(son)

for (_,v) in x.items {
 println(v)
}
`
the let converts the `T?` to a `T`

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I updated my answer now that you gave us the actual error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary is not defined to store an optional value. It is just the assignment operator that accepts an optional value because giving it `nil` will remove the whole key from the dictionary.

The problem you are having is that you are trying to mutate your property `items` in a non-mutating method. You need to define your method as mutating:

```
mutating func append(o: T?) {
    if let newValue = o {
        items[newValue.hashValue] = newValue
    }
}
```

There is certainly no problem assigning an optional variable to a non-optional value:

```
var optionalString : String? = "Hello, World"
```

In the same way, it is perfectly valid to assign a dictionary's key to a non-optional value:

```
var items : [Int:String] = [:]
items[10] = "Hello, World"
```

You can then assign the key to nil to remove the key entirely from the dictionary:

```
items[10] = nil
```

Also, I think you have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a hashValue is and how to use it. You should not pass the value of hashValue to a dictionary as a key. The dictionary calls hashValue on the value you provide, so you are having the dictionary take the hashValue of the hashValue.

**There is no guarantee that a hashValue will be different from all other the hashValues of different values**. In other words, the hash value of "A" can be the same hash value as "B". The dictionary is sophisticated enough to handle that situation and still give you the right value for a particular key, but your code is not handling that.

Comment: I understand that about hash values. The reason I use it is for a dumb implementation of a Set collection that I didn't see Swift has. I use a dictionary for the fast look-up and then store the value accordingly. It's just a small exercise in Swift, not production code.

Comment: @AvihuTurzion ok, as long as you understand that you have the potential to overwrite old values with new values unintentionally

Comment: @AvihuTurzion, but just marking the method as "mutating" should fix your immediate compilation error

Comment: If only they had proper errors. I was hunting for the wrong thing :/

Comment: @AvihuTurzion Ya, the errors in swift definitely need some significant work. One good rule of thumb is that when you get an error about an operator like subscript, switch the code to use the long name instead. In this case, changing the code to items.updateValue(newValue, newValue.hashValue) give you the error "Immutable value of type 'Dictionary<Int, T>' only has mutating members named 'updateValue'

Comment: If you want a set, create a dictionary with nothing as value.

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed store a non-optional value in a `Dictionary` and in general you can pass an object of type `T` whenever a `T?` is expected.

The real problem is that you haven't told the compiler that `T` is `Hashable`.

You have to put a  type constraint on `T`, using `T: Hashable`. You can do this at a class level (I suppose this method lives inside a generic class), like so

```
class Foo<T: Hashable> {
    var items: Dictionary<Int, T> = [:]
    func append(o: T?) {
        if let newValue = o {
            items[newValue.hashValue] = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the mess up, I should have included the entire code to begin with. I have told the compiler that `T` is `Hashable`. The problem is, as far as I can tell is that `items[Int] = T?` and I am assigning `T`.